# How could I interactively create an invoice and preview it on WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, grid, invoice, gridcontrol

I'm creating a trial project wherein my window has two grids, left grid is sort of a table that has labels and textboxes each row and asks for a specific part of the invoice like item, name, address stuff like that and the right grid is to show a preview of the invoice that the left side is creating.

I thought about using a document viewer on the right side but I thought that anything I open there would be static and if I put values on the textboxes on the left grid, it wouldn't matter since I opened a standalone document to view on the right grid.

I thought about just creating a table out of the right grid and have the default values and populate the other ones when a user types something on the textbox and make it function as the preview but then I don't know how would I go about and printing it and also, it has about 45 rows which I couldn't fit in the grid without it being unreadable (because I had to cram 45 rows of data inside that small grid)

So is there a tool in the toolbox that could potentially create a interact-able grid? I tried the grid control but I can't seem to only make it show 4 columns because that's all I need, I don't want it to show E and the rest of the alphabet because I want it to resize accordingly with only 4 columns to make it more readable.

Oh and I also have devexpress installed so you guys could also recommend something I can use from there. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best solution since it does what I wanted it to do.

I created a scroll view and placed a grid inside it then set the length accordingly to show it in a reasonable size and let the scroll bar do its magic for me to see the rest of the grid without compromises of the content's size.